# Como excluir um elemento HTML criado pelo JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Estou criando um contador de pontos para um jogo que minha família joga, estou com dificuldade de excluir o elemento divPlayer (o jogador), já tentei de várias formas mas não consegui espero que vocês possam me dar uma dica, desde já agradeço.

Contador Pontinho

```
<header class="main_header">Contador Pontinho</header>

<main>  
    <section class="principal">          
        <section class="player_register">
            <input type="text" name="player_name" class="player_name" placeholder="Nome do Jogador">
            <input type="button" value="Novo" class="add_new_player" onclick="newPlayer()">
        </section>

        <section class="game_area">
            <!--Were the game will take place-->
        </section>
    </section>
</main>
<script>


    var player =  {}
        var gameArea = document.querySelector(".game_area")


        function newPlayer() {

           player.name = document.querySelector(".player_name").value

           if(player.name.length == 0 || player.name.length > 12) {

               alert("[ERRO]. Nome grande demais ou inválido!")

          } else {

              player.points = 0

              let divPlayer = document.createElement("div")

              divPlayer.innerHTML = `
                  <div class="player">                 
                        <img src="images.jfif" alt="" class="player_img">
                        <text class="name">${player.name}</text>
                        <input type="button" value="${player.points}" class="add_points">
                        <input type="button" value="❌" class="delete_player">                
                 </div> `
        
             gameArea.style.padding = "1px 10px 1px 10px"

             gameArea.appendChild(divPlayer)

             let buttonDelete = document.querySelector(".delete_player")
             buttonDelete.addEventListener("click",deletePlayer(divPlayer),false)
        
    }
}

         function deletePlayer(element){
              console.log("deletou",element)
              gameArea.style.padding = "0px 10px 0px 10px"
              element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Você deve usar uma função anônima ou *arrow function* ao definir o evento clique do botão de deletar: `btnDel.addEventListener('click',  () => deletePlayer(divPlayer))`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Primeira coisa a se fazer é remover esse trecho do código

```
let buttonDelete = document.querySelector(".delete_player")
buttonDelete.addEventListener("click",deletePlayer(divPlayer),false)
```

de dentro da sua função de que adiciona um novo jogador `newPlayer()`

Depois dentro da `divPlayer` onde você define os seus elementos html, coloque a função `deletePlayer(this)` no evento `onclick` passando o `this` como parâmetro.

```
divPlayer.innerHTML = `
                  <div class="player">                 
                        <img src="images.jfif" alt="" class="player_img">
                        <text class="name">${player.name}</text>
                        <input type="button" value="${player.points}" class="add_points">
                        <input type="button" value="❌" class="delete_player" onclick="deletePlayer(this)">                
                 </div> `
```

Agora dentro da sua função `deletePlayer(element)` substitua essa linha `element.parentNode.removeChild(element);` por   `element.parentNode.remove();`. Devendo ficar assim:

```
function deletePlayer(element) {
  gameArea.style.padding = "0px 10px 0px 10px"
  element.parentNode.remove();
}
```

[link com as alterações feitas](https://jsfiddle.net/mL10f6j3/)